# Apache FOP Content overflow

Tags: apache, overflow, apache-fop

I am creating a PDF using Apache FOP and am trying to make my content overflow to the next page. I have tried setting 'overflow="paginate"' in the main block however this didn't work.

Has anyone else managed to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!